# How to change node.js swig module extension for .twig

Tags: node.js, swig

My templates files extensions are .html and i cannot use autocompletion of my IDE which require .twig extension to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you using it with express.js?

if so, you can use it like this:

```
app.engine('twig', cons.swig);
app.set('view engine', 'twig');
```